# Regarding Oauth 2.0 & https from October 1st

Tags: facebook, https, oauth-2.0

I want to know several things about new changes that will be applicable from October 1st that are Oauth 2.0 & https.

Will it be compulsory to provide https link when creating new application?

I have enabled https on main domain and my applications are on subdomain so do I need to acquire certificate for subdomain also?

Also as mentioned in roadmap fb_sig parameter will be deprecated, so do I need to upgrade all my applications to Oauth 2.0 in order to make them work?

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You must have ssl sertificate for your domain. It's not important where you buy or any other thing. facebook only look that if link is secure or not ( https)

So if you don' t have wildcard for your subdomains you have to buy wildcard for subdomains or ssl sertificate for each subdomain.